# Ноль или не ноль python

Tags: python, map, lambda

Есть некий функциональный код

```
print(any(map(lambda x: x != 0, map(int, input().split()))))
```

Выведите True, если среди введенных чисел есть хотя бы один нуль, или False в противном случае.

не могу понять, как при следующем вводе заставить делать правильный вывод:

Тест 1
Входные данные:
3
4
19
14
Вывод программы:
False

Тест 2
Входные данные:
7
8
8
8
12
12
11
28
Вывод программы:
False

Тест 3
Входные данные:
7
0
20
9
14
5
29
4
Вывод программы:
True

Скрин текущего вывода при

```
print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, map(int, input().split()))))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поменяйте `!=` на `==`

Comment: @andreymal в таком случае, у меня всегда True

Comment: Не наблюдаю такого у себя, при `==` все три теста выводят правильный результат на моём компьютере

Comment: И кстати определитесь, должна ли быть одна строка с несколькими числами или всё-таки несколько строк в каждой по одному числу

Comment: Не понятно, что это за скриншот такой, что где как вы вводите и запускаете. Кроме того, на скриншоте вы вводите несколько строк, но ваш код читает только одну первую строку и ни единой строки больше

Comment: @andreymal
Полный текст задания - Проверьте, есть ли среди данных N чисел нули.

Формат ввода

Вводится число N, а затем N чисел.

Формат вывода

Выведите True, если среди введенных чисел есть хотя бы один нуль, или False в противном случае.

Comment: Если формат ввода относится ко всему вводу, значит нужно читать весь ввод, а не только первую строку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое ощущение, что вы неправильно считываете числа, попробуйте так:

```
n = int(input())
print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, (int(input()) for _ in range(n)))))
```

Без лишней функциональщины:

```
n = int(input())
print(any(int(input()) == 0 for _ in range(n)))
```

**UPD.**

В одну строку:

```
print(any(int(input()) == 0 for _ in range(int(input()))))
```

В одну строку максимально функциональный вариант от **andreymal**:

```
print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, map(lambda _: int(input()), range(int(input()))))))
```

Comment: `map(lambda _: int(input()), range(int(input())))` раз уж функциональщина

Comment: Да, согласен, благодаря @andreymal я понял, что проблема в считывании, но, задачу нужно решить в 1 строку.
Пока не могу придумать как это сделать.

Comment: @BeerAndBear, не знаю зачем такая потребность, но добавил в UPD

Comment: @andreymal, хороший вариант, сочетается с тем, что было в вопросе :) Я охренел от количества скобок, как будто на лиспе пишу, хех: `print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, map(lambda _: int(input()), range(int(input()))))))`

Comment: @andreymal @gil9red я конечно все понимаю, но этого я не понимаю.
чтобы было проще, прохожу курс на coursera, и там сейчас функциональное программирование. 
Конкретные примеры не проходят:
```
print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, (int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))))))
```
код рабочий, но не проходит. В чем проблема не пишет, но подозреваю что в for _ in

Comment: @BeerAndBear, а второй вариант в прошел `UPD`? Оба вариант, кст, одинаковый результат дадут

Comment: Фух, спасибо.
В итоге прошло:
print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, map(lambda _: int(input()), range(int(input()))))))
Но, теперь надо разбираться что значит lambda _:

Answer (score 2):

Ребята, честно, не понимаю зачем вам тут лямбда и map.

```py
any(int(element) == 0 for element in input().split())
```

Comment: К сожалению, такой код система не приняла, судя по всему, посчитав его слишком не "функциональным", как я понял из-за for.